# Google Sheets - Combine multiple columns into one with unique values

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I currently have 6 columns that are populating from another sheet with the query formula, based on column name. I would like to combine these 6 columns into one column, eliminating duplicates, and listing them all in one-singular column. I've tried the following without success:

- FILTER(UNIQUE(A2:A, B2:B, C2:C, D2:D, etc.),ISBLANK({same list})=FALSE))
- FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(A2:A, B2:B, C2:C, etc.))
- FILTER(UNIQUE({A2:A,B2:B;C2:C; etc.}), LEN(UNIQUE({A2:A,B2:B;C2:C; etc.})))

The catch seems to be that sometimes the columns will be blank. I think google sheets is either reading them as blank and giving me an error, or sees there a query'd set of data and it's unable to retrieve the list.

Any recommendations? [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, if I'm understanding you correctly:

`=QUERY(FLATTEN(A2:F),"WHERE Col1 Is Not Null")`

Comment: This worked! Originally did not because I tried to use all caps for "Col1". Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: Using newer functionality made available since the original post, this would be more succinct: `=TOCOL(A2:F, 3)`